# Redirect Outbound HTTP to port 53 iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, routing

I am new to iptables and would like to reroute all outbound HTTP traffic on my router from port 80 to port 53. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Eric

*Edit

I ran

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5300
```

That produced

```
iptables v1.4.6: unknown option `--to-ports'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

I then ran

```
opkg install iptables-mod-nat-extra
```

That produced

```
opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package iptables-mod-nat-extra
```

Thanks for help with this.

Eric

Comment: Is this on openwrt by any chance? If you're getting that message then the kernel's not compatible with redirecting via iptables - at least that route.

Comment: Please don't ask us how to circumvent network security measures. After all, we are the people who implement those security measures!

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by doing this?

Answer (score 3):

From your question it isn't clear what you want to do (or even that you know what you want to do), so here's a few pointers:

- **-t nat** -- gets you to the NAT table, this is where you want to be for what it sounds like you want to do
- **-A POSTROUTING** - the `POSTROUTING` table is for AFTER the routing decision has been made. Usually means the traffic is on its way out. You can change SOURCE addresses, but not DESTINATION addresses here.
- **-A PREROUTING** - the `PREROUTING` table is for BEFORE the routing decision has been made. If you want to change where the packet goes, then do it here. It sounds like this is what you want.
- **-A OUTPUT** - the `OUTPUT` table is for outbound packets that originated (or were otherwise modified) by a local process, and specifically NOT for packets that your server is handling in the role of a router/switch/gateway. This is a convenient place to put rules for traffic that your server is generating on its own.
- **-j REDIRECT** - [doesn't do what you think it does](http://www.linuxtopia.org/Linux_Firewall_iptables/x4508.html). Probably not what you want.
- **-j SNAT** - Source Network Address Translation. This is for changing the source address or source port. If you want to change where the packet came from, then use this target
- **-j DNAT** - Destination Network Address Translation. This is for changing the destination address or port. If you want to change where the packet goes, then use this target.

So, to modify traffic passing through a router destined for port 80 and change that destination to port 53, you can use this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to :53
```

This will do exactly what you asked for. Specifically, it will make all websites unreachable.

Comment: Hi, if I want to `DNAT` passing-thro traffic on my router, can I use `-A OUTPUT` in some way?

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be asking about [traffic originating at the router itself](https://serverfault.com/questions/510265/redirect-outbound-http-to-port-53-iptables#comment575507_510267), you should not be using the PREROUTING chain but the OUTPUT chain. Also, if the traffic is originating at the router itself, it is a much better option to change the configuration of the processes initiating the connection to simply use a different destination port.

If this is not working for you for whatever reason, you can use the DNAT target like

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to :53
```

note though that since the destination servers are *not* expecting HTTP requests at port 53, you likely would not get any meaningful responses unless you revert the translation at some point behind the captive portal. You might consider tunneling through to a host under your control outside the restricted network (e.g. using OpenVPN) and simply route the requests through the tunnel instead.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 53`

Further instructions/reference: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/

Comment: Thanks, but when I ran that it produced the above results.

Comment: I commented on the question. Looks like the router's kernel doesn't support redirects with iptables. You could put squid or similar in front of your router to redirect. On that note, *why* do you need to redirect?

Comment: Ok, i'll look at implementing squid. I'm using a OpenWRT router without a gui and would like to connect to connect its wan port to a network with an HTTP captive web portal capturing traffic from port 80. I am looking to redirect traffic to an open port in order to bypass that portal since I can not authenticate to it due to not having a browser. Thanks for your help

Comment: Note that "REDIRECT" is intended to redirect to *local* ports - this seems not to be what the question is about.